# Why isn't this RewriteRule working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite `/user/username` to `/user-profile/?user=username` without changing the URL in the address bar. I have the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^/?user/(.*?)/?$ /user-profile/?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/user-profile/\?user=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?user-profile/$ /user/%1? [L,R=301]
```

This changes `/user/username` to `/user-profile/?user=` in the address bar. The query string var "user" is left blank but it somehow loads the correct user profile. So I think the first rule is working but the second rule and it's condition must not be since the URL in the address bar is changing. What can I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to switch the order of your two rules.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things. You have 2 rules, one that internally rewrites and the other redirects the browser. You *must* have your redirect come before the rewrite, otherwise the internal rewrite gets reprocessed by the redirect rule. The other thing is the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is literally the first line of the HTTP request, and it starts with a method, not the request URI:

```
GET /user-profile/?user=qwerty HTTP/1.1
```

is what it will look something like. That means you need to alter your regex to account for those other parts of the request that's not the URI. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /user-profile/\?user=([^\&\ ]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?user/(.*?)/?$ /user-profile/?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried what you suggested but I got a redirect loop (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS). Could other rewrite rules be affecting this? I also the following further down the page:RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/ping
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]